# Ext.util.JSONP.request never calls its callback

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

Based on GeoTweet example from Sencha, I am trying to develop an Android App using PhoneGap and Sencha that reads a JSON as shown in this example code: https://github.com/nelstrom/GeoTweets/blob/master/public/javascripts/geotweets.js

My code looks like:

```
var refresh = function() {

        alert("Yo");
        Ext.util.JSONP.request({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/actors.json',
            callbackKey: 'callback',
            params: {
                time : new Date().getTime()
            },
            callback: function(data) {
                alert("Yo Yo");
                data = data.results;

            }
        });
    };
```

Here, the first alert is displayed but Ext.util.JSONP.request is never executed (I don't see request being logged by my server) I am not sure is going wrong here.

Comment: Why are you using JSONP and not regular Ajax? You are calling localhost and not a different domain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of localhost put in 10.0.2.2 so you URL will be http://10.0.2.2:3000/actors.json